# Why isn't my jquery.html() and jquery.append() code readable by NVDA readers?

Tags: html, jquery, accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

I can't seem to make an NVDA screen reader work with jQuery on the insertion of HTML to the DOM.

I need my application to meet accessibility standards (e.g. WAI-ARIA) with dynamic content being added to my page on an Ajax post-back.

Here is my code that is not being read by NVDA... what am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function addText() {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "some test";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>NVDA</h2>

<div id="testarea">Some test area</div>
<div id="test" aria-describedby="testarea" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals" role="region"></div><br />

<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="addText()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://codetalks.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_ARIA_Live_Regions_for_dynamic_content

Comment: I've tried the code samples you provided from the link here and with NVDA, it doesn't read the content that is added.  I tried it with an innerHTML, a jquery.html(), and a document.createTextNode().  Nothing...tried it with IE and chrome.  Do you have a working sample?  Do I need to include a JS file or a CSS file or something to make thsi work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**WCAG**

These are the WCAG recommendations about client-side scripting relating to the content update : http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/client-side-script.html

In particular so far I've found

- SCR21: *«Using functions of the Document Object Model (DOM) to add content to a page»* (see http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR21.html)
- SCR-26: *«Inserting dynamic content into the Document Object Model immediately following its trigger element»* (see http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/client-side-script.html#SCR26)
- G75: *«Providing a mechanism to postpone any updating of content»* (see http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G75.html)
- G76: *«Providing a mechanism to request an update of the content instead of updating automatically»* (see http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G76.html)
- G186: *«Using a control in the Web page that stops moving, blinking, or auto-updating content»* (see http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G186.html)

---

**ARIA**

about ARIA roles take a look at `aria-live`, `aria-relevant`, `aria-atomic` and `alert` properties:

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live

> Indicates that an element will be updated, and describes the types of updates the user agents, assistive technologies, and user can expect from the live region.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-relevant

> Indicates what user agent change notifications (additions, removals, etc.) assistive technologies will receive within a live region. See related aria-atomic.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-atomic

> Indicates whether assistive technologies will present all, or only parts of, the changed region based on the change notifications defined by the aria-relevant attribute.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden  (if ajax result make visible or hidden some regions of the page)

> Indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible or perceivable to any user as implemented by the author. See related aria-disabled.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#alert

> Alerts are used to convey messages to alert the user. In the case of audio warnings this is an accessible alternative for a hearing-impaired user. The alert role goes on the node containing the alert message. Alerts are specialized forms of the status role, which will be processed as an atomic live region.

---

**Other Resources**

Articles about NVDA screen reader and accessibility on ajax updates and other relevant resources:

http://tink.co.uk/2009/06/screen-reader-support-for-ajax-live-regions/
http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2008/02/ajax-and-screen-readers-content-access-issues/

http://ejohn.org/blog/ajax-accessibility/  (here it's suggested a code snippet about a live region in which content is updated)

```html
<p id="users-desc">A list of the currently-connected users.</p>
<ol aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals"
    aria-describedby="users-desc" id="users">  
     ... 
 </ol>
```

Comment: I tried this and several other derivations of the modification I just added to my OP and NVDA doesn't read my changes.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is the closest answer I could find.  I finally got it working with <ul><li> but still can't get it to fly with <div><span>  I'll post a new question as it's dissimilar enough (my new problem).  Thanks for hte help.